# read file from server with some offset

Tags: python, http

How can I read file from server starting with some offset (Similar behavior to **wget -c**)? What headers I must send to server? What futures must server support?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use the `Range` header in the request. But you may use it only if the server informs you that it accept range request by `Accept-Ranges` response header.

This is an example session. Suppose we are interested in getting a part of [this picture](http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2238/2758537173_670161cac7_b.jpg). First, we send a HTTP `HEAD` request to determine: a) if the server supports byte ranges, b) the content-length:

```
> HEAD /2238/2758537173_670161cac7_b.jpg HTTP/1.1
> Host: farm3.static.flickr.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2010 12:22:12 GMT
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
< Expires: Mon, 28 Jul 2014 23:30:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Aug 2008 06:13:54 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 350015
```

Next, we send a `GET` request with the `Range` header asking for the first 11 bytes of the picure:

```
> GET /2238/2758537173_670161cac7_b.jpg HTTP/1.1
> Host: farm3.static.flickr.com
> Accept: */*
> Range: bytes=0-10
> 
< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2010 12:26:54 GMT
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
< Expires: Mon, 28 Jul 2014 23:30:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Aug 2008 06:13:54 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Range: bytes 0-10/350015
< Content-Length: 11
<
```

This is a hex dump of the first 11 bytes:

```
00000000  ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46  49 46 00                 |......JFIF.|
0000000b
```

For more info see the [Range header specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35) in HTTP RFC 2616.

Comment: in the range header specification it is mentionned that Accept-range is optionnal a server may accept ranges without mentionning it is a bit convoluated but the only true test is to try

Comment: @Xavier Yep, if the server doesn't accept ranges, then it may respond with 406 or 400 status code.

Answer (score 3):

In http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

> Note that ‘-c’ only works with ftp
> servers and with http servers that
> support the Range header.

In https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

> Examples of byte-ranges-specifier
> values (assuming an entity-body of
> length 10000):
>
> ```
>   - The first 500 bytes (byte offsets 0-499, inclusive):  bytes=0-
>     499
>
>   - The second 500 bytes (byte offsets 500-999, inclusive):
>     bytes=500-999
>
>   - The final 500 bytes (byte offsets 9500-9999, inclusive):
>     bytes=-500
>
>   - Or bytes=9500-
>
>   - The first and last bytes only (bytes 0 and 9999):  bytes=0-0,-1
>
>   - Several legal but not canonical specifications of the second
> ```
>
> 500
> bytes (byte offsets 500-999, inclusive):
> bytes=500-600,601-999
> bytes=500-700,601-999

So you should send

```
Range:bytes=9500-
```

> To test if a server support it you can test the accept-range as such
>
> Origin servers that accept byte-range requests MAY send
>
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> but are not required to do so. Clients MAY generate byte-range
> requests without having received this header for the resource
> involved. Range units are defined in section 3.12.
>
> Servers that do not accept any kind of range request for a
> resource MAY send

> ```
> Accept-Ranges: none
> ```
>
> to advise the client not to attempt a range request.