# How to load a URL and only get back the last 20k of it 

Tags: php, http-headers

I have been made aware of the Accept-Range header.

I have a URL that I am calling that always returns a 2mb file. I don't need this much and only need the last section 20-50k.

I am not sure how to go about using it? Would I need to use `cURL`? I am currently using `file_get_contents()`.

Would someone be able to provide me with an example / tutorial?

Thanks.

EDIT: If this isn't possible then what is post on about? [Here ...](http://kuza55.blogspot.com/2008/02/http-range-request-range-request.html)
EDIT: Ulrika! I'm not insane.

Comment: of course this is possible.  That is, for servers supporting it, which most do.  I will post example code later tonight, but really you should just be able to set the appropriate headers and make the request with curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using the `Range` header, provided the server supports it. See the [HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35). You would want to send a header in the following format in your request:

```
Range: bytes=-50000
```

This would give you the last 50,000 bytes. Adjust to whatever you need.

You can specify this header in `file_get_contents` using a context. For example:

```
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'header' => "Range: bytes=-50000\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to `file_get_contents()` and dump that to a passthrough 'cache' file on disk, then you could use the unix/linux `tail -c` to only grab back the last 20kb or so. This doesn't mitigate the actual transfer, but gets that 20kb into the application.

Comment: The transfer isn't a problem and TBH, I don't mind having to get the 2MB file. I just don't understand what people are saying when they are using this header. If it doesn't do this, what does it do ...

Comment: What's up with the downvote... this is a *legitimate* solution. It wasn't condescending and was correctly worded.

Comment: Because the question explicitly asks how to not download the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203217/read-file-from-server-with-some-offset) for an example of the HTTP headers sent and received

Answer (score -4):

you can't do that. You're going to have to load the entire file (which is sent in its entirety, sequentially, by the source server), and just discard most of it.

What you're asking is like "I'm tuning to this radio station on my car stereo and I only want to hear the last 5 minutes of the show, without having to wait for the rest to complete or change channels".

Comment: But the browser knows how large a file it; there is nothing stopping it getting total size and returning the range you specify. This has been talked about with resuming downloads when a connection drops and should be the same principal. With a radio show, you don't know how long it is to get the last 5 minutes, if you did, then you could.

Comment: How does this work with resumable downloads then? Does that only work for the person sending the file?

Comment: p.s I don't mind being wrong, I am just intrigued what this other guy was on about :)

Comment: Please see my edited post? I have posted a link to what I am talking about.

Comment: @jwenting, your analogy to a radio show is inaccurate.  The content is there, the server knows how big it is, the client knows what parts it wants.  This is most certainly possible.