# Start read at line X from website without using bandwidth?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bandwidth

I am trying to read a website using a bufferedReader but it is using 3Mbps of my   internet and im trying to get it down, I know exectly on what line the text I want   to read is so is there a way i can skip to that line and only read the text   without using bandwidth on stuff I dont want and if this isnt working is there   another way I can read that line without using this much bandwidth.

Comment: That's not how HTTP requests work

Comment: @Kon in that case is there a better way to get the data from a website than using a bufferedReader that reads a InputStream or is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Not all web servers support skipping to a specified offset. For those that do, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203217/read-file-from-server-with-some-offset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using HTML Parser like [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org). Jsoup uses a parse tree and it can be really fast. 
Either way I don't think that there is a way to start from specific line, unfortunately.